# Are there any stotras for curing baldness or enhancing physical beauty

Tags: mantras, rig-veda, stotra, yajur-veda, vedic-rituals

Yes I do know that this is a materialistic request but honestly some of us can’t shed the materialistic part of life that easily and I believe that our ancient yogis had an answer for everything in hymns and stotras. Please do tell if any stotras or vidyas exist for curing hair loss

Comment: If there was there would be very few bald Indians, right?